# C order of operations?

Tags: c, operators

Can someone please explain me why the result of the following code is 9? I am really confused..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{ 
   int a = 3, rez;
   rez = a-- + (-3) * (-2);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: To understand your confusion better it would be interesting if you told us what you thought the result should be (by going step by step through the calculation).

Comment: `3 + (-3 * -2) == 3 + 6 == 9`?  The decrement changes `a` to `2` after the old value is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler aimed exactly. So therefore if I used --a the result would have been 8?

Comment: " if I used --a the result would have been 8?"  --> could try compiling and run it.

Comment: @CatalinGhita that is correct.

Comment: @chux I did that after I assumed it was 8,and it is correct. Now I feel foolish about this question

Comment: Good that you ran it too.

Comment: @chux is there a difference between unary and binary + or - ? ( referring to order of operations) and how to distinguish them if that is true?

Comment: @CatalinGhita unary  + and -  is higher order of precedence than binary + and -.   `-x - 1` is the same as `(-x) - 1` and not `-(x - 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
rez = a-- + (-3) * (-2)
```

is *parsed* as

```
res = ((a--) + ((-3) * (-2)))
```

and is *evaluated* as "the result of `a--` is added to the result of `(-3) * (-2)`, and the final result is assigned to `res`".

Postfix `--` has higher precedence than unary `-`, which has higher precedence than binary `*`, which has higher precedence than binary `+`, which has higher precedence than `=`.

Note that *precedence* and *order of evaluation* are not the same thing - it's not guaranteed that `a--` is evaluated before `(-3) * (-2)`, or that `-3` is evaluated before `-2`; all that's guaranteed is that the *result* of `(-3) * (-2)` is known before it can be added to the *result* of `a--`.

Futhermore, the *side effect* of `a--` doesn't have to be applied immediately after evaluation.  This means that the following is a perfectly valid order of operations:

```
t1 = a
t2 = -2
t2 = t2 * -3
res = t1 + t2
a = a - 1
```